# How does FastText support online learning?

Tags: classification, word-embedding, online-learning, incremental-learning

I'm using FastText pre-trained-embedding for tackling a classification task, but I saw it supports also online training (incremental training) for adding domain-specific corpus.

How does it work?

As far as I know, starting from the "model.bin" file it retrains the model only on the new corpus updating the old word-vectors, is it right?

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/423 ? It seems the official FastText does not support incremental learning yet.

Comment: yeah exactly i saw that link. Probably i misunderstood. Anyway i opted for the pretrained one with Wikipedia corpus. Thanks for your answer, hoping and waiting for the official "incremental" features in Fast Textt as soon as possible :).

Answer (score 1):

The pull request #1327 (https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/1327)

**Allows for:**

1. test after each epoch
2. checkpointing
3. training on large data which does not fit into memory (largest I tested was 1.6TB)
4. finetuning already trained models

The trained model is indistinguishable from a model that was created by an original tool and can be used for inference by the old code.